# Architecture: Javascript event tracking in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to make a custom tracking system for web events. I have looked into multiple per-excsiting systems, but I want something terribly simple - yet **very** accurate.

I want to be able to track the following:

1. Page view even
2. Time on that page

or:

1. Video started playing event
2. Time of video watched

My first initial thought was to do a simple javascript reporting back to the server, but what happens if the user closes the window? How do I know they stopped viewing? And how can I get accurate measurements down to 1/10th of a second? So I thought of a websocket solution, as it know when a user has discounted. I ended up with Socket.io, but I want to make sure there is no better or smarter way to achieve this?

How would you approach his challenge? What is the smartest way to engineer this?

Comment: If the reporting is precise, does it also need to take place *immediately*, or would it be acceptable for there to be a delay, such as on the next page load, before the (precise, accurate) report gets sent to the server?

Comment: I'm sorry! Kinda new to this! Well it would be acceptable to log after the event has 'completed' meaning another event was fired, like loading a new page.

Answer (score 0):

A Websocket connection which reports back to the server frequently was my first thought as well, but if you send 10 messages every second, even that might be too much for a websocket, especially when connectivity isn't top-notch.

Since the server doesn't require the information absolutely immediately, consider *batching* requests instead - save/update the information into Local Storage every 0.1 seconds, but don't send it to the server then - instead, every 30 or 60 seconds, or on pageload, take the current data in Local Storage and send it to the server, and clear Local Storage so that the next request a minute from now doesn't send duplicate data.

Comment: I was thinking to send a 'start event' and an 'end event' and calculate the difference. If I use sockets, I would also know when the user disconnected from the socket and close and missing 'end events'?

Comment: You don't have to have the server keep track of the events - do it all on the local browser. If a user closes the page, your local Javascript can detect it, and then you can send the info to the server on the next pageload.